# Using 'this' in a function prototype - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand some prototypical concepts of JavaScript which I don't use quite often. Here I have two same methods one for Array another for Function. One works, another not. Could you please explain what is the difference here?

```
var arr = ['test'];
var string = 'test';

Array.prototype.print = function(){
        console.log(this);
}
Function.prototype.print = function () {
        console.log(this);
}

arr.print(); // logs the arr with value 'test'
string.print(); //logs string.print is not a function
```

Comment: `Function.prototype.print` => `String.prototype.print`

Comment: Strings aren't instances of Function so they don't inherit from Function.prototype. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are 'extending' the Function `prototype` but calling the `print` function on a `String`.

Change your code to:

```
String.prototype.print = function () {
        console.log(this);
}
```

And it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

The error says the problem in your code, that you are not defined the print function on String prototype instead you did on Function which you are not using at all.

```
String.prototype.print = function () {
//^^^^^--
        console.log(this);
}
```

```js
var arr = ['test'];
var string = 'test';

Array.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log(this);
}
String.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log(this);
}

arr.print(); // logs the arr with value 'test'
string.print(); //logs string.print is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one works because you did it right. You added `print` function to `Array`.

The second one doesn't work because you did it wrong. You need to add `print` function to `String`:

```
String.prototype.print = function () {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

string inherit String, you can add print method to String prototype like this:

```
String.prototype.print = function () {
        console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[Array,Function,String,Object].forEach(n=>n.prototype.print=function(){
console.log(this);
});
```

A shortform...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to extend a function prototype and accessing the String prototype. You are misunderstanding the prototype inheritance concept

```
var arr = ['test'];
var string = 'test';
var someMethod = function(){ /* some code */ };

Array.prototype.print = function(){
        console.log(this);
}

String.prototype.print = function () {
        console.log(this);
}

//Extending the prototype of Function
Function.prototype.print = function () {
        console.log(this);
}


arr.print(); // logs the arr with value 'test'
string.print(); //logs string.print is not a function
someMethod.print(); // this will trigger the print method
// extended in Function Prototype.
```

**Update**

> Very interesting point I realised due this post in Javascript. It is
>   you can treat Function prototype as other prototoypes. Imagine you are
>   extending the functions of a function itself ( seems like one of a
>   kind inception ). So there are interesting methods like `call, apply ,
>   bind`. So we can extend the functionality of even a function. Correct me if I am wrong, Unlike
>   in any other language I can think of, where extending function seems
>   to be impossible. Given that we are not given privilege to touch the
>   source code of that language. Very powerful feature in JS.

Comment: @RacilHilan But eventually you are adding a new method into String prototype. Also String is  primitive datatype in JS. This print will be available to all variables with datatypes as string. I haven't seen such behaviour in other languages, like extending methods in primitive datatype. Can you please quote an example